# python time(milli seconds) calculation

Tags: python, time

How to calculate milliseconds,from the code below.

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a

>>> c

>>> c.days
0
>>> c.seconds
4
>>> c.microseconds
```

Comment: related: [Get current time in milliseconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5998245/4279)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
milliseconds = (c.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + c.seconds) * 1000 + c.microseconds / 1000.0
```

Comment: This answer is wrong!if time delta is 1 minute exactly,result will be 0,not our expect!

Answer (score 14):

Or, new since 2.7:

```
c.total_seconds()*1000
```

(https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)