# Using time.strf() to get the current time, and building on that

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code below:

```
interval_time=int(input('how many seconds each interval?'))
print(time.strftime("%H:%M"))
while time.strftime("%H:%M")!=str('19:45'):
    time.sleep(interval_time)
    winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit",winsound.SND_ALIAS)    
winsound.PlaySound("SystemEnter",winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

The thing is, I know how to get current time. I want it to look something like:

```
while *script_first_ran_time*!=*script_first_ran_time+30minutes*
```

I know how to convert the minutes, but it keeps re-taking the current time and adding 30 minutes to it. How do I make the initial time.strf() remain constant?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're down-voting, please explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've decided to make this task harder by using string representation of times. As these strings have no concept of being dates, performing date-related operations on them is troublesome. As an alternative, you should use dedicated library designed to work with dates and times, namely [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Boilerplate code would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

thirty_minutes_later = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)
while datetime.now() < thirty_minutes_later:
    pass  # do something
```

Here, `datetime.now` returns special objects that represents current time. `timedelta` returns special objects that, when added or subtracted from `datetime` instance, returns another `datetime`, shifted in time according to `timedelta`'s state.

Also, notice that I've changed your condition from *not equal* to *bigger than* - it'll stop processing even if you won't hit your time spot precisely (and with millisecond resolution, you'd have to be extremely lucky to hit that).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answering! While this is a different approach, it's a teachable moment nonetheless. I was wondering, you said making this task harder. How can I use the time as integer?

Comment: You can reuse [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998245/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-python) to get current timestamp in numeric form. Still, I do not understand how operating on raw timestamps is easier than using datetime module.

Comment: That was just out of curiosity, already learned one new thing today, why not another? Thank you very much!