# Curses breaks a time.sleep() when terminal's size has been changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, ncurses, python-curses

I  faced with behavior which I cannot understand.

```
import curses
import time

myscreen = curses.initscr()

y, x = myscreen.getmaxyx()
i = 0

while y >= 24 and x >= 80 and i <= 23:
    myscreen.addstr(i, 0, 'Python curses in action!')
    myscreen.refresh()
    y, x = myscreen.getmaxyx()
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

curses.endwin()
```

This code will write 24 strings with 1 second interval and it's ok.
But when I will begin to change size of terminal window during execution, strings will appear on screen much faster then 1 string per second.
Could you please explain this behavior and maybe get advice how to "protect" my time.sleep()?
Thanks.

P.S. without curses sleep() works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you resize your terminal, the terminal emulator sends a signal (`SIGWINCH`) to the program(s) using it for input/output.  In your example, that interrupts `time.sleep()`.

Rather than use `time.sleep()`, you could use the curses function `napms()` (which waits a given number of milliseconds).

Starting with your current program, you can see the time-behavior better if you print it out (adapting an answer from *[Get current time in milliseconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978116/4518274)*):

```
import curses
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start_time = datetime.now()

# returns the elapsed seconds since the start of the program
def elapsed():
   dt = datetime.now() - start_time
   ms = (dt.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + dt.seconds) * 1000 + dt.microseconds / 1000.0
   return ms / 1000.0

myscreen = curses.initscr()

y, x = myscreen.getmaxyx()
i = 0

while y >= 24 and x >= 80 and i <= 23:
    myscreen.addstr(i, 0, 'Python curses in action ' + "%.3f" % elapsed())
    myscreen.refresh()
    y, x = myscreen.getmaxyx()
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

myscreen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

curses has a function like sleep, but in *milliseconds*: [`napms`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.napms).  Using that, you'll get more more consistent behavior, because ncurses handles the `SIGWINCH`, [restarting](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tty/lib_twait.c#L449) the `napms` as needed to get the requested time-delay.  When I change that `time.sleep(1)` to

```
    curses.napms(1000)
```

the program continues to "sleep" for one second while the terminal is resized.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `time.sleep()`:

> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of
>   seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a
>   more precise sleep time. **The actual suspension time may be less than
>   that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep()
>   following execution of that signal’s catching routine**. Also, the
>   suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount
>   because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.