# use same time format in Java and Python

Tags: java, python, timestamping

I have 2 modules, the first one is generating `ingestion_time` as shown below

```
Long ingestion_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The sample output of this `ingestion_time` is

> ingestion_time = 446453570778734

Now I have the second module in python which is generating detection_time for the same event  as shown below

```
detection_time = time.time()
```

The sample output of this `detection_time` is

> detection_time = 1524807106.92

I want to have them in the same format so that I can get latency as

```
latency =  detection_time - ingestion_time
```

**Both modules are on the same system.**

Please help!

---

**Edit 1**

by using

```
now = long(time.time())
print "detection_time  = %s "%now
```

I get `detection_time` as

```
detection_time  = 1524808352
```

which is still not comparable with `generation_time` as the number of digits is different

```
generation_time = 1524808352170
```

---

**Answer**

using below-mentioned code solved my issue

```
now = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print "detection_time  = %s "%now
```

Comment: Transfer and parse to and from ISO-8601 .

Comment: it gave me detection_time  as 1524807726552, but I want in the format 446453570778734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to get the time in Mili seconds.

```
import time
millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print millis
```

For reuse:

```
import time

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

Then:

```
>>> current_milli_time()
1378761833768
```

This answer has been found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998245/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The value that you provide

```
ingestion_time = 446453570778734
```

is simply not correct (based upon System.currentTimeMillis())

All you need to do is convert the python date by multiplying by 1000

```
detection_time = 1524807106920 == System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  Please see updated question

Comment: and as I mention, they are off by a factor of 1000.  One is in seconds and the other is in second.  Either divide one or multiply the other