# how to use the timestamp() cypher function in py2neo?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I've been running this cypher

`CREATE (b:Request {created_at: timestamp(), depth:$depth})"`

which relies on the cypher [`timestamp()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-timestamp) function. 
The documentation calls out

> The timestamp() function returns the equivalent value of datetime().epochMillis.

meaning I could do the time calculation on the [server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998245/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-python), 
though having access to the scalar functions I'd like to know if it's A) possible, and B) if possible how to use.

`b = Node("Request", created_at= timestamp(), depth= 0)` did not even a little bit work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you do this, you are generating a timestamp *client-side* rather than *server-side* and you should be aware of the implications of this, re clock sync, etc.

That said, you'll need to pass an actual Python `datetime` instance (Cypher can only be evaluated server-side):

```
from datetime import datetime
b = Node("Request", created_at=datetime.now(), depth=0)
```

You'll need to make sure you're running at least py2neo 4.2 and Neo4j 3.4 for this to be available.

Comment: It does not work when calling graph.create(b)