# What is python3 equivalent of Date.now() of javascript?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

In JavaScript, I can assign:

`var now = Date.now();`

Then use now to calculate as a number variable

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
```

In python3, Using upper code doesnt seem helpful. Any idea what is equivalent of Date.now().

Comment: Start with `datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()`. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-Python-DateTime-string-into-integer-milliseconds

Comment: Duplicate of [Get current time in milliseconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998245/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-python)

Comment: Oh didnt realize that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `time` module.

```
>>> import time
>>> int(time.time() * 1000) #for getting the millisecs

1601559393404
```

Comment: For time in milliseconds, try: `int(time.time() * 1000)`

Comment: As @Mr.Polywhirl pointed out you can just multiply the string by 1000 and take the integer part of it to get the same result as of JS.

Answer (score 0):

[Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. The Python 3.3 and later equivalent is:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now_ms = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
```

Without `tz=timezone.utc`, [datetime.timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) will use a naive datetime, usually set to your local time with timezone, daylight savings time, etc. This can be a subtle source of bugs, when going from Python to Javascript, between development environments and production, or around daylight savings time transitions.