# mongodb extract data between dates saved with javascript Date.now

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection called `foo_collection` where the documents contains a field called `createdby` that uses javascript `Date.now()` to save the timestamp.

an example would be

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "618a669ea3bff474f6fe4767"
    },
    "widgetid": "ddbae9a2-4156-11ec-905a-02cf95edae88",
    "publisher_id": "938ecebe-1089-11ec-8bd1-0a57868782b0",
    "impression_id": "b6bfc0bc-1dc4-11ec-850e-0a57868782b0",
    "logid": "ksaeqkqe65",
    "createdby": {
        "$numberLong": "1636460191573"
    }
}
```

As you can see the field `createdby` uses `$numberLong` to save the data.

And, [According to the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) `The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.`

How to query the collection `foo_collection` using `pymongo` such that I get the datas between two date range ?

Comment: Have you tried using `datetime` to convert the time you want to query to epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Date.now()` which returns a number and not a `Date` object you can simply do a number comparison

````
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      createdBy: {
        $gt: *some_number*
      }
    },
    {
      createdBy: {
        $lt: *some_number*
      }
    }
  ]
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

converting python `datetime` into timestamp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156493/what-is-python3-equivalent-of-date-now-of-javascript)

```
start = datetime.strptime('2021-11-10', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() * 1000
end = datetime.strptime('2021-11-11', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() * 1000

db. collection.find({
  "createdby": {
    "$gt": start,
    "$lt": end
  }
})
```