# Why are python and javascript showing different timestamp for the same date

Tags: javascript, python, timestamp

Below is the javscript code that I am using to get the timestamp of a particular date
I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873379/2481350)

```js
var myDate = "12-11-2021";
myDate = myDate.split("-");
var newDate = new Date(myDate[2], myDate[1] - 1, myDate[0]);
console.log(newDate.getTime());
```

The output is `1636655400000`

and below is the python code I am using to get the timestamp I got it from [the first comment and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64156493/2481350)

```
datetime.strptime('2021-11-12', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()*1000
```

The outout `1636675200000.0`

Why are the two timestamps different ?

Comment: Javascript has an unintuitive way to give the month as argument. January is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Date constructor with these parameters:

```js
var newDate = new Date('2021', '11', '12');
```

Which is basically representing the date `2021-12-12` and NOT `2021-11-12` as you would expect.

The reason is that in JS the month is zero-based, meaning `0` is January up to `11` for December.