# Time duration of user input

Tags: python, input, time, duration, raw-input

I'd like to know how long it takes a user to enter an input that I record with raw_input().
I.e. does it take them 1 second or 10 seconds to enter something on the command line.

Is there an established way of doing this, or would I need to invent my own way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is second resolution (not millisecond/microsecond), you can surround the code with `time.time()` to get the beginning/ending times, then subtract.

```
import time

start = time.time()
in_str = raw_input("Enter the thing:")
end = time.time()
elapsed = end-start
print "That took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds. Man, you're slow."
```

If you want it at a greater resolution, take a look at the code presented here: [python time(milli seconds) calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905403/python-timemilli-seconds-calculation)

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар I'm a very quick typist ;) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `timeit` module.

```
import timeit

def read_input():
    global in_str
    in_str = raw_input('Enter text: ')

in_str = ''

s = total_time = timeit.timeit('read_input()', number=1,
                               setup='from __main__ import read_input')

print(in_str)
print(s)
```

The s will be in seconds, but it has microsecond granularity on Windows and 1/60s on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you can use time.time() for this purpose

```
import time
start=time.time()
inp=raw_input(" enter the input")
print start-time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time.time()` before and after the input, then just take the difference. The answer will be in seconds.

```
>>> import time
>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> s = raw_input("enter something")
hello
>>> t2 = time.time()
>>> enter_time = t2-t1
>>> enter_time
17.92899990081787
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start = time.time()
in_str = input("Enter the thing:")
end = time.time()
elapsed = end-start
print(elapsed)
```

If you use this it should give you the answer in and precisely to a long list of decimal points. @TheSoundDefence for most of this code.