# How to get milliseconds delta in Python?

Tags: python, time

I want to get the time delta between two timestamps: `time1` and `time2`, and the result should be shown in millseconds. For example:

```
time1=17:00:00:121
time2=17:01:00:121
```

the result will be 60*1000=60000.

I can't find such a method in python (mostly shown in seconds), and `datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()` only returns seconds without the minus of minutes, hours and days.

So anyone can tell me how to make it, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27929936/283649 is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at timedelta...

```
timedelta = date1 - date2
```

https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects which gives you the delta in days, seconds and microseconds.

Eventually you might want to try https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905403/python-timemilli-seconds-calculation thanks,there is clear answer.